# Pandas loop taking way to much time - better way?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a loop that is taking way too much time and I wonder if there is a better way? Or if I am making rookie mistakes?

The reason I am doing a loop is that the first value is different and the need for previous values.

```
# create var and set to 0
df [ 'amt_model' ] = 0

# create the cashflow variable
df [ 'cf' ] = df [ 'cash_in' ] - df [ 'cash_out' ] + df [ 'transfer' ]
```

Now I loop through the range of months to create the 'amt_model' values.

```
for i in range ( len ( df ) ):

    # adjust for the first month
    if i == 0:
        df [ 'amt_model' ].iloc [ i ] = df [ 'contrib' ].iloc [ i ]

    else:

        amt1 = df [ 'amt_model' ].iloc [ i - 1 ] * (1 + df [ 'pct_model' ].iloc [ i ])
        amt2 = df [ 'cf' ] [ i ] * (1 + df [ 'pct_model' ].iloc [ i ] / 2)

        df [ 'amt_model' ].iloc [ i ] = amt1 + amt2
```

This is taking up way too much time to loop through only 20 or 50 values.

```
index_values- start 19:28
index_values - end 19:42
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please, can you at least take the time to write one question with a [mcve], including data?

Comment: be happy to, but I don't fully understand what you would like? sorry, I am not a coder by profession. This code is a just a small part of a far, far bigger app. way too much to post.  Just looking for someone to proof my methodology. Are there obviously errors causing it to eat so much time? Thanks!

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution, with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['cf','cash_in','cash_out','transfer','contrib','pct_model'])
for c in df.columns:
    df[c] = np.random.rand(100)*100

print(df.head())

          cf    cash_in   cash_out   transfer    contrib  pct_model
0  18.478061  80.073920  19.041986   8.859406  85.695653  18.174608
1  96.172043  72.786434  54.215755  76.859253  87.934012  47.415420
2  79.026521  63.252437  29.094382  23.460806  30.547062  36.154976
3  64.630058  85.409417  98.469148  84.905463  32.859257  75.908211
4  54.121041   8.823944  48.835937   5.194054  17.004900  25.130477
```

Iterate over `rows` to create a new `array` and assign to `df`

```
#amt_model is your future column
amt_model = [df.loc[0,'contrib']] #init with first row

#Calling df[1:] will get all your df except first row, iterate over it
for i, row in df[1:].iterrows():
    _amt_model = amt_model[-1] * (1 + row.pct_model)
    amt_model.append( _amt_model + row.cf * (1 + row.pct_model/2))

df['amt_model'] = amt_model #assign to your df

print(df.amt_model.head())

0    8.569565e+01
1    6.525182e+03
2    2.439506e+05
3    1.876432e+07
4    4.903214e+08
Name: amt_model, dtype: float64
```

Performances : `100 loops, best of 3: 13.7 ms per loop`

Is that what you could expect?

---

**Alternatives**

If yes you can try it in one line:

Opt1:

```
amt_model = [df.loc[0,'contrib']]
[amt_model.append( amt_model[-1] * (1 + row.pct_model) + row.cf * (1 + row.pct_model/2) ) 
for (i,row) in df[1:].iterrows()]

df['amt_model'] = amt_model

#Performances:   
100 loops, best of 3: 14.7 ms per loop
```

Opt2 - With `apply`:

```
amt_model = [df.loc[0,'contrib']]
df[1:].apply(lambda row: amt_model.append( amt_model[-1] * (1 + row.pct_model) + row.cf * (1 + row.pct_model/2) ),
             axis='columns')

df['amt_model'] = amt_model

#Performances:
100 loops, best of 3: 11.7 ms per loop
```

Comment: When you use shift for amt_model column you get only '0'. It need update in each iteration.

Comment: Updated with a new try

Comment: interesting - thank you very much.  will test them both and let you know

Comment: ok, you are welcome. Tell me if some unexpected behaviour happens

Comment: WOW!  using the first solution of creating a list and then putting that list into the df at the end -  just changed life as I know it.  I went from almost 16 seconds to 1 second.  Now I need to rewrite a lot more code based on this approach.  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade it by pull 'amt2' from loop. I will use something like this:

```
df['amt2'] = df [ 'cf' ] * (1 + df [ 'pct_model' ] / 2)
df['amt1_1'] = 1 + df[ 'pct_model' ]

for i in range(len( df)):
    # adjust for the first month
    if i == 0:
        df [ 'amt_model' ].iloc [ i ] = df [ 'contrib' ].iloc [ i ]
    else:
        amt1 = df [ 'amt_model' ].iloc [ i - 1 ] * df['amt1_1'].iloc[i]

    df [ 'amt_model' ].iloc [ i ] = amt1 + df['amt2'].iloc[i]
```

You need upgrade 'amt_model' variable in each iteration so I don't see any diffrent option.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this one

```
df.loc[0,'amt_model' ] = df.loc[0,'contrib']
amt1 = (df.loc[:(len(df)-2),'amt_model']) * (1 + df.loc[1:, 'pct_model'].reset_index(drop=True))
amt2 = (df[ 'cf' ]) * (1 + df[ 'pct_model' ]/2)
df['amt_model'] = amt1 + amt2
```

Taking `len(df)-2` gives you the `t-1` value, and `df.iloc[1:]` gives you the `t` value. Same length.

Comment: I was hoping to find a way without doing a loop.  Cant wait to try. Thanks!